# Using interp3 in matlab

Tags: matlab, octave

I am trying to understand how to use the 3D matlab interpolation function `interp3`. I have tried different options but it keeps giving errors. I've got 3 arrays which contain the coordinates of `V`:

```
X = ndgrid(-246.4529 :2.5: -246.4529 + 100*2.5 - 1);
Y = ndgrid(-45.6577  :2.5: -45.6577  + 213*2.5 - 1);
Z = ndgrid(-211.00   :2.5: -211.00   + 140*2.5 - 1);
```

and the other 3 arrays with the coordinates where I would like to interpolate:

```
Xp = ndgrid(-255.21 :5: -255.21 + 50*5  - 1);
Yp = ndgrid(-50.66  :5: -50.66  + 108*5 - 1);
Zp = ndgrid(-215.00 :5: -215.00 + 86*5  - 1);
```

And then I've got `V` which is a sample values vector, specified as a vector of that defines the values at the sample points.

```
 npoints = 100*213*140;
 for n=1:npoints 
     i = rem(n-1,dims(1)) + 1;
     P(n,1) = X(i);
     j = rem(fix((n-i)/dims(1)), dims(2)) + 1;
     P(n,2) = Y(j);
     k = ceil(n/(dims(1)*dims(2)));
     P(n,3) = Z(k);
    % store the sample 
     V(n,1) = mat(i,j,k);
 end
```

Now I would like to interpolate `V` to obtain `Vp`:

```
Vq = interp3(X,Y,Z,V,Xp,Yp,Zp)
```

but I've got:

```
Error using griddedInterpolant
The grid vectors do not define a grid of points that match the given values.

Error in interp3 (line 130)
        F = griddedInterpolant({X, Y, Z}, V, method,extrap);
```

Any ideas of how could I use `interp3` with my data?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`Interp3` works with `meshgrid` not `ndgrid` ...

Personnaly, as I'm always confused when trying to understand mixed orientation for grid vectors with `meshgrid` (and size of the arrays it returns)**, I prefer to work with `interpn` that works from `ndgrid`

```
% Input grid
x = (-246.4529 :2.5: -246.4529 + 100*2.5 - 1);
y = -45.6577  :2.5: -45.6577  + 213*2.5 - 1;
z = -211.00   :2.5: -211.00   + 140*2.5 - 1;

% Output grid
xp = -255.21 :5: -255.21 + 50*5  - 1;
yp = -50.66  :5: -50.66  + 108*5 - 1;
zp = -215.00 :5: -215.00 + 86*5  - 1;

% Data
V = randn(length(x),length(y),length(z));
```

Then using `interpn` and `ndgrid`:

```
% Interpolation
[X, Y, Z] = ndgrid(x, y, z);
[Xp, Yp, Zp] = ndgrid(xp, yp, zp);
Vq = interpn(X,Y,Z, V, Xp,Yp,Zp);
```

**: I think `meshgrid` always inverts the two first dimension

Comment: @_CitizenInsane Thanks for your help. I've tried that now but unfortunately I am getting `NaNs` in `Vq`. Any ideas why? Instead of using `V` in my code, I've used `mat`: `Vq = interpn(X,Y,Z, double(mat), Xp,Yp,Zp);` The values of `mat` go from 0 to 1.0e6, all positive values.

Comment: You are getting `NaNs` because you are extrapolating outside initial domain (for instance xmin is -255.21, while initial range started at -246.4529) ... you can use `extrapval` (see `interpn` documentation) to define the value to be used outside domain.

Comment: TIP: For extrapolated values you can also *virtually* expand initial x,y,z domain beyond/til final xi,yi,zi domain ... for instance by repeating first and last point on dimensions, this in order to repeat last known value ... or put extra zero to linearly decay toward zero (or any other value at your convenience).